# Python pynput.keyboard.write() sending text repeatedly the same text and unrequested part of text

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events, hotkeys, pynput

I'm trying to make some mapped.HotKeys to transfer some text.
Using pynput, I made a function to transfer raw text and another to transfer just numbers.
Whith pynput.keyboard.GlobalHotKeys, I've mapped 'ctrl+alt+1' for te first and 'shift+ctrl+alt+1' for the second.
Using the first shortcut, a "¹" caractere is printed before the sequence wanted (like normal use of these keys).
Using the second, the first text, folowed by the second (only digits), is printed repeatedly (as more the keys are manteined pressed, more times the text is printed).
Ex.: the string '45.785.422/0001-25'
ctrl+alt+1 results - ¹45.785.422/0001-25
shift+ctrl+alt+1 results - 45.785.422/0001-25457854220001254578542200012545785422000125457854220001254578542200012545.785.422/000...
The code:

```
from pynput import keyboard as kbd
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import re

txt_base = '45.785.422/0001-25'

# keyboard = Controller()


def send_text():
    keyboard.write(txt_base)


def clean_text():
    txt_array = re.findall(r'\d+', txt_base)
    txt_cln = ''.join(txt_array)
    keyboard.write(txt_cln)


hotkeys = kbd.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<ctrl>+<alt>+1': send_text(),
    '<ctrl>+<shift>+<alt>+1': clean_text(),
})

with hotkeys:
    hotkeys.join()
```

Somebody can help me with these issue? Tks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, maybe the program get's confused that you press combination 1 all the time. I had similar problem and in my case, it happened because my key combination was containing keys, that I write at the same time with `keyboard.write()`.

In your case, maybe the program bugs, because you press `ctrl+alt+1` but you also write `45.785.422/0001-25`, which contains `1`. So since you hold `ctrl+alt` for a little and print something with `1` in it, you make the bot think that you hold `ctrl+alt` and spam `1` and so the `keyboard.write()` repeats.
As far as I know, unfortunately pnput can't distinguish user from PC when typing keys.

There are workarounds though.
One way is, you can change the shortcut to something that can't appear in the thing you are writing with `keyboard`

The other way around can be to replace `send_text()` with a delay that waits for you to release the hotkeys

Something like this:

```
def send_text():
    keyboard.write(txt_base)

def run_send_text():
    time.sleep(0.5)     # time it takes for a regular person to release the keys
    send_text()

hotkeys = kbd.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<ctrl>+<alt>+1': run_send_text(),     # this time runs after 0.5 seconds
    '<ctrl>+<shift>+<alt>+1': clean_text(),
})
```